# Angular : How does ng-click directory parses the expression without doubly curly brace?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view as follwing,

```
<li ng-repeat="img in people.images">
 <img ng-src="{{img}}" ng-click="setImage(img)">
</li>
```

Its working. But my doubt here is, the attribute `ng-click` should have been set the img inside doubly braces to be executed as in `ng-src` as `ng-click="setImage({{img}})"`. Its shown below,

```
<li ng-repeat="img in people.images">
 <img ng-src="{{img}}" ng-click="setImage({{img}})">
</li>
```

But the later is not working.

How the expression is parsed here and how does `ng-click` vary from `ng-src`?

I really confused here. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: `ng-click` is an Angular directive, so it evaluates angular expressions. `setImage` is declared on the `$scope` - as is `img` (in it's own newly created child scope from `ng-repeat`

Comment: @tymeJV - then, it should have been given like `{{setImage(img)}}` right? Still I confused here.

Comment: Nope, `ng-click` already evaluates the `$scope` variables, so theres no need for the `{{}}` - `{{}}` is used to output `$scope` variables to the view.

Comment: @tymeJV - then why not `ng-src` do the same? that is also there in the same `scope` right? `How does it really vary from ng-src?`

Comment: @krishna I think it's just the way they are defined in Angular. If you look at the docs, it says `ng-src` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) should be set to a string that may contain `{{}}`, and then it says `ng-click` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) should be set to an **expression**

Comment: @krishna then why not ng-src do the same? > Surely because you can still want to pass a hard-coded path, like simple `src` does. For instance:  `ng-src="/img/myImg.jpg"`. You don't expect `img` as being evaluated but hardcoded simply. When dealing with angular functions, there is no concept of hardcoded call, that means nothing.. so it ALWAYS binds to the scope. My 2 cents ;)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the following: Some of the directives use expressions, some don't. This is how they "vary" from each other. You may use the angular documentation to see, which directive use expressions and which don't.

Example for ng-click: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick It uses an expression:
[image]

Example for ng-src: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc It doesn't use an expression:
[image]

`ngClick` lets you define a JavaScript-like expression, while `ngSource` lets you define an usual String, where you also may define an expression, inside the double braces. According to the AngularJS documentation, everything inside of the double braces is also an expression: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression.

I think that the "need" to have the difference between "Expression" for "ngClick" and "String" for "ngSrc" come from the original attributes they derive from: `onclick` and `src`.

The attribute `src` is used to reference a resource as String, while using the attribute `onclick`, you may use javascript. The usual case is to call a function in `onclick`, i.e. `onclick="doSomething();"`. I assume that angularjs uses these attributes as a base, this is why the workflow is similar. `ngClick` lets you use usual javascript expressions, while `ngSrc` lets you use a String and add a `{{}}` expression if you need to.

The benefit of using `ngSrc` with a variable, for example `ngSrc="http://localhost/{{myRessource}}"` is, that it is evaluated only after `$scope.myRessource` is set, not before. It uses the observer pattern to render the view as soon as the variable is set, as far as I know.

According to your example, the second one which doesn't work:

```
<li ng-repeat="img in people.images">
 <img ng-src="{{img}}" ng-click="setImage({{img}})">
</li>
```

It doesn't work because of a syntax error. `ngClick` uses javascript expression, and the syntax of `setImage({{img}})` is not correct - you would not use double brackets around variables either in a javascript function.

**Further:** `$interpolate` and `$parse`
Like stated above, some directives, like `ngClick` use `expressions`, while other directives like `ngSrc` use plain `Strings` combined with `{{}}`. The difference between the two on angularJs side is the following:

- a directive using an expression is evaluated by angularjs using [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) (Read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) from heading "Text and attribute bindings")
- a directive using a String is evaluated by angularjs using [$interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) (Read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) from heading "Context")

**Example**:

```
$scope.varOne = "asdasdasd";
var test1 = $interpolate("http://localhost/{{varOne}}");
$scope.displayOne = test1($scope);
```

At first, we declare a variable `varOne`. `$interpolate` returns a function which needs to be called with the scope, we will bind this to the local variable `test1`. Then we will call `test1` using the `$scope`. As a result, we will have on `displayOne` the String `http://localhost/asdasdasd`.

```
var test2 = $parse("1+5-3");
$scope.displayTwo = test2($scope);
```

`$parse` is evaluating javascript expressions, as a test we may use the calculation "1+5-3". After calling `test2`, the result will be `3`.

I prepared a fiddle, so you can see this: http://jsfiddle.net/wSN54/6/

You may also try using brackets in the `$parse` evaluation (the same that happens in your second example):

```
$scope.varTwo = 2;
$scope.varThree = 3;
var test2 = $parse("{{varTwo + varThree}}");
$scope.displayTwo = test2($scope);
```

This must resolve in an error, because the double braces are not used in usual javascript expression:
[image]

Check it out fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wSN54/8/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you put img param inside double brackets, when the page is rendered, you will notice that the parameter inside setImage function is a value of img. If you put img without brackets you will have rendered "setImage(img)" and in both case that will work.
Example:

imagine that you have one item in people.images model, and its for example "example.jpg". If you use brackets in setImage function, when the page is rendered you will see the attribute "ng-click=setImage('example.jpg')", in another approach you will have "ng-click=setImage(img)". In first case AngularJS don't need to parse value from your parameter, because you already put 'example.jpg' like a parameter, in another case AngularJS will parse value from img parameter/item before your function is executed.

Comment: When I use the 2nd way, Its been rendered as you said but click event is not getting fired.

Comment: You mean your 2nd way, with brackets ?

Comment: @krishna Think about it - what will be rendered is something like `ng-click="someFunction(SOME_VALUE)"` - where `SOME_VALUE` isn't surrounded by quotes, so it will look for a scope variable called `SOME_VALUE` (which won't exist), and the `ng-click` won't run. We've already provided an explanation of **why** `ng-src` and `ng-click` are different, and you just need to use them correctly

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; ng-src `$interpolate` the argument as template where ng-click `$parse` the expression

Long version

Copied from angular official docs

```
param=ngSrc, type=template

param=ngRepeat, type=repeat_expression
```

details refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

What is expression - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

What is template(markup) - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Comment: small mistake: `ngClick` does not use `$eval`, check here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression `Angular does not use JavaScript's eval() to evaluate expressions. Instead Angular's $parse service processes these expressions.`

Comment: @meberhard, I double check the angular source code. I make mistake. You are right. Thanks. I updated the answer.